# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'NoneType' and 'tuple' with random generator?

Tags: python, random, tuples, operands

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'NoneType' and 'tuple'

I need a quote or image to print in place of `%s` but can't seem to figure out how?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import random

if __name__=="__main__":

print("Content-type: text/html")
print()

    quotes=["The course of true love never did run smooth.", "Life every man     holds dear; but the dear man holds honor far more precious dear than life.",
"To thine own self be true, and it must follow, as the night the day, thou canst not then be false to any man.", "Poor and content is rich, and rich enough.",
"If you have tears, prepare to shed them now.", "Words without thoughts never to heaven go."]


pics=["https://ebooks.adelaide.edu.au/s/shakespeare/william/portrait.jpg", "http://images.wisegeek.com/william-shakespeare-painting.jpg",
  "https://mareseosullivan.files.wordpress.com/2012/01/william-shakespeare.jpg", "http://bookhaven.stanford.edu/wp-content/uploads/2010/10/shakespeare-4.jpg",
  "http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/02699/shakespeare_2699766b.jpg", "http://www.poetryfoundation.org/uploads/authors/william-shakespeare/448x/william-shakespeare.jpg"]




    print ("""
<html>
<head>
<title>QOTD: Shakespeare </title>
</head>

<body>
<center> 
<img src="%s">
<p>
<font size="12"><b>The quote of the day is:</b></font>
<p>
<table>
    <tr>
    <td width="500"><font size="6">%s</font>
    </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</p>
</center>
</body>
</html>
""") % (random.choice(pics), random.choice(quotes))
```

Comment: @idjaw I had to change indentation on here to get the code to print correctly in my question. Can you let me know what you changed?

Comment: I ran your code on Python 2.7. When I ran it on Python 3 I replicated your problem. However, you really should fix your indentation in your question to give a proper representation of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably using python 3.X. The code you have works for python 2.X, but you need to change it as follows:

Instead of:

```
print (s) % (x, y)
```

Try this:

```
print (s % (x, y))
```